# Translate python dict to json

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying with jinja2 to traverse a python dict to json. I have the following python structure

```
examples:
   ex1: example1
   ex2: example2
```

With the following jinja2:

```
examples= [{{(examples|default({}))|tojson}}]
```

I am achieving

```
   examples=[{"ex1":"example1","ex2":"example2"}]
```

How can i achieve

```
examples=[{"ex1":"example1"},{"ex2":"example2"}]
```

Comment: I am using jinja2 for my purposes

Comment: where this strange `·` symbols come from?

Comment: @BoarGules It is not the line breaks, in the desired output the list contains two dictionaries (or objects?) instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to put - in before my keys in order to create it as an array.

```
examples:
 - ex1: example1
 - ex2: example2
```

So now my code gives the result with two objects as below

```
examples=·[{"ex1":"example1"},{"ex2":"example2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
examples = {'ex1': 'example1',  'ex2': 'example2'}
out = []
for k,e in examples.items():
    out.append({k:e})
print(out)
```

with a call to json if really needed?